# Apache basic authentication prompt not showing

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm trying to setup very basic username/password protection for my site using apache v2.4.7. I have the following in my sites conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            DocumentRoot /var/my.site
            DirectoryIndex index.html

            <Directory /var/my.site>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Options +ExecCGI
                AddHandler cgi-script .pl
                Require all granted
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Authentication Required"
                AuthUserFile "/etc/my-site/.htpasswd"
                Require valid-user
            </Directory>
            ...
```

...but it's serving all requests without any auth challenges. I've also tried putting the auth options into their own separate `<Location>` block, but it's the same. I haven't explicitly enabled any additional auth mods myself, but I've checked `auth_basic`, `authn_core`, `authn_file` and `authz_user` mods and they're all enabled.

Comment: and is it doing this for http requests or https only?

Comment: Well, there's nothing listening on port 80 or any other port, so it's just 443 (https). Is that a problem, do you think? Trying to use an auth prompt like this over HTTPS? I'll change to HTTP and see...

Comment: Sure what am I talking about, of course it should be allowed over HTTPS, it's HTTP that it's not allowed over because it's insecure. Apache doesn't allow auth config in the .conf file for non-ssl.

Comment: Have a google at what "Require all granted" means.

Comment: I never even noticed those duplicate lines for require, so stupid. Thanks buddy!